# Как во время выполнения цикла изменить target для threading

Tags: python, многопоточность, очередь

Есть следующий пример:

```
import threading
from queue import Queue


def myfunc():
    while True:
        num = queue.get()
        print(num / 10)
        queue.task_done()

def myfunc2():
    while True:
        num = queue.get()
        print(num * 10)
        queue.task_done()


queue = Queue()
for t in range(3):
    t = threading.Thread(target=myfunc)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
mylist = []
for x in range(10):
    for i in range(10):
        for i in range (10):
            mylist.append(i)
    for i in mylist:
        queue.put(i)
    queue.join()
```

Как, в данном случае, во время выполнения цикла, изменить target для тредов на `myfunc2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и в прошлом вопросе, предлагаю использовать пул потоков, а не создавать его самому.

```
import time
import threading
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor

DELAY = 2
COUNT_THREAD = 3

def myfunc(value):
    time.sleep(DELAY)
    print(value, value / 10, threading.current_thread().name)

def myfunc2(value):
    time.sleep(DELAY)
    print(value, value * 10, threading.current_thread().name)


executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(COUNT_THREAD)
for x in range(10):
    for f in (myfunc, myfunc2):
        executor.submit(f, x)
```

Comment: Это не совсем то, что нужно. В приведенном вами примере обе функции будут выполнены последовательно, но мне нужно менять target во время наполнения очереди.

Comment: Паралельно в разных потоках. Для подтверждения, вставьте перед печатью в обе функции задержку `time.sleep`. Очередь в данном коде не надо наполнять, `ThreadPoolExecutor` сам является очередью.

Comment: Это работает, но не уверен, что подойдет конкретно мне, я попробую встроить в ту "шляпу", что написал, и отпишусь.

Comment: Есть проблема, с которой столкнулся, `main thread` не тормозит и продолжает выполнять цикл и это вызывает проблемы, так как вызов `executor.shutdown(wait=True)` не позволяет больше вызывать `executor.submit()`, а цикл продолжает работать. Есть другой способ заставить `main thread` дождаться выполнения очереди?

Comment: Разобрался, все работает

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, этот код вам поможет.
Его следует использовать вместо вашего цикла `for t in range(3)`

```
func=myfunc
for i in range(3):
    if i==3:
        func=myfunc2
    t = threading.Thread(target=func)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
```

Comment: В таком случае будет создано только по одному треду на функцию, плюс они будут выполнятся однворменно, в то время как мне нужно чтобы они как бы менялись. То есть цикл наполняет очередь, и в какой-то момент переключает функцию, которая обрабатывает очередь

Comment: @BrainDrill исправил

Comment: В данном случае, будет создан поток, который одновременно с предыдущими потоками будет обрабатывать очередь, а не поочередно, нужно чтобы мы создавали фиксированное кол-во потоков и они внутри одного цикла переключались между разными функциями